# Apache (HTTPD) virtual host entry not working

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I am setting up apache on my machine to serve some static content. I am running into the following issue:

The public IP address of my instance is: **54.203.56.245** and the domain which maps to this instance is **timelines.co**. The DNS propagation has happened long back and when using another server, I am able to successfully access my website like this: http://timelines.co

With HTTPD, I am able to access my website like this: http://54.203.56.245 (you can try it out in your browser). However, I am not able to access it like this: http://timelines.co -- I get a 'timeslines.co refused to connect' error (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED).

What could be the reason for this? I have been playing with Virtual Hosts, but to no avail.

This is what my httpd.conf looks like - I have added this at the bottom:

```
IncludeOptional /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/*.conf
```

This is what /etc/httpd/sites-enabled looks like:

```
timelines.co.conf -> /etc/httpd/sites-available/timelines.co.conf
```

This is what /etc/httpd/sites-available/timelines.co.conf looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName timelines.co
    ServerAlias www.timelines.co
    DocumentRoot /var/www/timelines.co/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/timelines.co/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/timelines.co/log/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Edit 1:**
On my local computer, I am able to open the website in Internet Explorer but not in Microsoft Edge and Chrome.

---

**Edit 2:**
I cleared all browsing data (everything) on chrome, and now the website is loading on chrome too. I have not cleared things on Edge yet and the website is not loading on Edge.

---

**Edit 3:**
I cleared all browsing data (everything) on Edge, and now the website is loading on Edge as well. It seems like some sort of cache issue. Not sure what though. Maybe a clash between DNS lookups stored in browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have something in your HostFile that is blocking or making your browser get the Connection Refused. I checked over your Vhost and it looks correct. Your site actually works for me and I get the Success! The timelines.co virtual host is working!
Also, I checked for your DNS Record timelines.co also and it looks correct also
A records
IPv4 address    54.203.56.245

Comment: There is nothing in the hosts file - it is all commented out.